# Can you apply for a Schengen visa from the US if your H1-B is expired?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, h1b-visas

I have extended I-797 for my H1-B (but not stamped yet, stamped visa is expired). Can I apply for a Schengen visa in the USA? Or, do I have to get the US visa stamped and, only then, I can apply for a Schengen visa from within the USA?

Comment: Can you provide visa officer with any supporting documents that prove you're waiting for a visa extension?